# C++ overloading virtual = operator

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, interface, operator-overloading

here is the code for my question:

```
class ICommon
{
public:
 virtual ICommon& operator=(const ICommon & p)const=0;
};

class CSpecial : public ICommon
{
public:
 CSpecial& operator=(const CSpecial & cs)const
 {
  //custom operations
  return *this;
 }
};
CSpecial obj;
```

Basically: I want the interface ICommon to force it's descendants to implement = operator but don't want to have any typecasts in the implementation. The compiler says "can't instantiate an abstract class.
Any help/advice will be appreciated.

Comment: What is it that you want to achieve? Do you want all extending classes to implement `operator=` with their own type at the most derived level, or do you want to implement a polymorphic `operator=` that can be used through references/pointers to the base interface?

Comment: As with David, I'm not sure what exactly you want to achieve. If what you want is to make sure that the derived classes writer produces their own copy assignment operator (thus preventing the compiler from generating an implicit one), writing an abstract virtual operator will not work because even if the writers implements this at the derived class (necessarily ICommon& operator=(const ICommon&)), the compilers will still implicitly generate ISpecial& operator=(ISpecial&).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To echo what Naveen said, the `operator=()` defined in CSpecial isn't compatible with the one defined in ICommon, and results in an overload rather than an override.  While you can have covariant return types (as you've done), the arguments themselves can't be covariant.

Furthermore, you've defined the `ICommon::operator=()` as const, which seems counterintuitive.  In the derived class, you've made it non-const (as expected), but again, this makes the function signatures further incompatible.

Naveen's `clone()` idea is probably your best bet.  Otherwise, you can pass an ICommon const reference to your CSpecial `operator=()` and attempt some `dynamic_cast<>()` magic internally, but that smells funny.

Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

That is because the signature of the function in `CSpecial` is different from the pure virtual function you defined in the abstract base class. You can use the [virtual copy constructor](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/virtual-functions.html#faq-20.8) to do the copying. Basically you define a pure virtual function `ICommon* clone() = 0` in the base class, and implement it in each derived class. When called this function will create a copy of the object on which it is called.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a recursive template to achieve what you want:

```
template<typename T>
struct IAssignable {
  virtual T& operator =(const T&) = 0;
};

struct Impl : IAssignable<Impl> {
  virtual Impl& operator =(const Impl&) { return *this; }
};
```

This does not, and can not, be used to force a copy constructor to be implemented.  So I'm not convinced it is that terribly useful, and you're probably better off with the `clone()` option others suggested.  But its a useful construct in general.

Answer (score 0):

> Basically: I want the interface
>   ICommon to force it's descendants to
>   implement = operator but don't want to
>   have any typecasts in the
>   implementation. The compiler says
>   "can't instantiate an abstract class.
>   Any help/advice will be appreciated.

Consider separating the public interface of the base class from it's (virtual) operation implementation:

```
class ICommon
{
public:
    ICommon& operator=(const ICommon & p)
    {
        if(this == &p)
            return *this;
        copy(p);
        return *this;
    }
protected:
    virtual void copy(const ICommon& p) = 0;
};

class CSpecial : public ICommon
{
protected:
    virtual void copy(const ICommon& p)
    {
        // TODO: copy values from p
    }
};
```